# Ошибка в переопределении метода del

Tags: python, классы

Есть код :

```
free_pc = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
daily_cash = 0


class Player:
    price = 100  # за час

    def __init__(self, nick, pc, hours):
        self.nick = nick
        self.pc = pc
        self.hours = hours
        self.cash = self.hours * Player.price
        global free_pc
        free_pc.remove(self.pc)  # удаляем пк из списка доступных
        global daily_cash
        daily_cash += self.cash

    def __len__(self):
        return self.hours

    def __str__(self):
        return f'user {self.nick} on {self.pc} pc played {self.hours} hours'

    def __del__(self):
        print(f'{self.pc} is free now')
        global free_pc
        free_pc.append(self.pc)


p1 = Player('qwe', 4, 5)
p2 = Player('asd', 2, 8)
p3 = Player('zxc', 1, 1)

print('свободные компы: ', *free_pc)
print(daily_cash)
print(p3)
del (p3)
print(free_pc)

пишет:

свободные компы:  3 5 6 7 8 9 10
1400
user zxc on 1 pc played 1 hours
1 is free now
[3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1]
4 is free now
2 is free now
```

почему при удалении p3 выводятся на печать те слова которых не должно там быть?я же не удалял другие объекты.Даже везде глобал поставил,все равно не то печатает,
вот тут можно посмотреть https://ideone.com/H25kTp

Comment: Вроде разобрался,при методе del  появляется сборщик мусора который удаляет объект,он смотрит что объект ни связан ни с чем.И в конце выполнения он вызывается уже для всех объектов.         Тогда почему он только для принта работает? То есть надо удалять объект и негде не писать об этом?Можно ли как то не допустить чтоб он не писал это для всех?

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под "почему он только для принта работает" ? Ваш переопределённый del выполняется весь целиком.

Comment: Ну и использование global нужно по возможности избегать. В вашем примере вместо глобальных переменных нужно просто использовать атрибуты класса.

Comment: Я имел ввиду следующее.Этот метод печатал что "пк освободился" затем он добавлял этот пк в список свободных компьютеров.Когда я его вызвал он сделал 2 эти вещи.И после сработал для других объектов,но он только написал что эти пк свободны, но не выполнил 2 часть,он не добавил эти пк в список.Типа если в __del__ методе будет print, то после выполнения программы  он выполнится для всех,а если что то другое то нет.Спасибо что ответили, но  пока надо еще разобраться с этим методом.
Понаставил везде глобал  т.к.сначала,думал что из за этого он печатает в конце все объекты.

Comment: Почему вы решили, что для этих двух объектов не произошло добавление в список? Оно произошло. Если вы в конец вашего del допишите print(free_pc) то легко в этом убедитесь.

Comment: Действительно добавляет,теперь я еще больше запутался. https://ideone.com/6bCUkl но ведь я же в конце программы распечатал free_pc
и там все было как надо,добавился 1 пк и уже потом после выполнения всего кода,через метод del туда зачем то добавились еще 2.
Наверное это надо было по другому реализовывать.Попробую разобраться чтоб самому ответить.

Comment: Просто когда программа заканчивается, срабатывает del для всех объектов, которые не были удалены до этого